# Skyscanner Travel API / use private Apikey / return 429

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, skyscanner

I want use Travel Api in my Android app

First Test Harness Demo API key (prtl6749387986743898559646983194)
returns 200, success Creating the Session and Polling the Session

However, while using the Dashboard private API key, it return `429 Too many request`

Is there anything I need to do for using private API key?

my code:

```
public void run(String u) {
    try {
        // SystemClock.sleep(500);
        url = new URL(u);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(50 * 1000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(50 * 1000);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        //        connection.setRequestProperty("If-None-Match", "no-store");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");

    /*    connection.setUseCaches(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);*/


        Log.v("Response", " parameter = " + Parameters);


        byte[] postData = Parameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(postData);
        os.flush();

        //  SystemClock.sleep(500);

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.v("Response", "Sending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        Log.v("Response", "Post parameters : " + Parameters);
        Log.v("Response", "Response Code : " + responseCode);
        Log.v("Response", "Message : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        String result = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
        SettionKey = connection.getHeaderField("Location").substring(result.indexOf("v1.0/") + 5, result.length());
        Log.v("Response", "SessionKey = " + SettionKey);
        connection.disconnect();
        //  SystemClock.sleep(500);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("Response", "Post Dead");
    }

}

public void get(String url) {
    try {
        Log.v("Response", "get");
        String url1 = url + "/" + SettionKey + "/?apiKey=" + apiKey;
        URL url2 = new URL(url1);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
        Log.v("Response", "url = " + url1);

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded.");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.setUseCaches(true);
        connection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        Log.v("Response", " " + connection.getHeaderFields());
        Log.v("Response", "code   = " + responseCode);
        Log.v("Response", connection.getResponseMessage());

        code = responseCode + connection.getResponseMessage();
        Flight.put("code", code);
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            setlist(br);
            //Log.v("Response","result = "+inputLine.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("Response", "read Dead.. ");
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("Response", "GET Dead ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got same problems. Then I find out that:

> Flights Live Pricing service is currently suspended.

You can check at [here](https://support.business.skyscanner.net/hc/en-us/articles/206800359-Which-services-can-I-access-and-what-are-the-rate-limits-)

My solution is using demo apiKey for dev, and waiting for their service re-launch.

Answer (score 1):

For first, I would recommend for you to use **Retrofit library** for HTTP-requests. 
It is more suitable, comfortable and faster than your way. It will use 10-15 strings of code in contradistinction to your method.
You can find it here:

[Retrofit IO](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) and
[Github documentation](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

And here are some basic requests for ScyScanner API which I use in my application:

```
@GET("reference/v1.0/locales?" + Config.API_KEY)
Call<Locales> getLocales(@Header("Accept") String accept);
```

Where Config.API_KEY is some String in Config class, which holds my API key. This request can help you to get locales list.

```
@GET("reference/v1.0/countries/{locale}?" + Config.API_KEY)
Call<Markets> getMarketCountries(@Header("Accept") String accept, @Path("locale") String locale);
```

To get market countries

If you would have any problems with using your API key try **to get new one.** It helped me. Good luck :)